# Русское литературное произношение

Tags: орфоэпия, запрос-ссылок

Захотелось заняться подробным изучением русской орфоэпии, освоить литературное произношение. Решил поработать со справочником Розенталя по литературному редактированию. Но в разделе «ОСНОВНЫЕ ПРАВИЛА РУССКОГО ЛИТЕРАТУРНОГО ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЯ» все изложено кратко и в общем, и мне, как человеку, который хочет начать с азов орфоэпии, этого недостаточно. Например, там упоминается ослабленный звук [а]. А про то, как он произносится, ничего нет.
Да и вообще мне почему-то кажется, что все там предельно сжато.

Какие бы вы могли посоветовать новичку пособия по изучению орфоэпии и русского литературного произношения, которые есть в электронном виде?

Answer (score 1):

Научиться произносить звуки без специальной подготовки по текстовому описанию не получится. Нужно слушать или -- еще лучше -- жить там, где говорят так, как вам интересно.

Можете почитать очерк в конце http://www.ruslang.ru/node/1405 (М. Л. Каленчук, Л. Л. Касаткин, Р. Ф. Касаткина.
Большой орфоэпический словарь русского языка),

раздел «Орфоэпия» из учебника С. В. Князева и С. К. Пожарицкой (https://www.labirint.ru/books/321466/),

Орфоэпический словарь русского языка под ред. Н. А. Еськовой (http://www.ruslang.ru/orfo14).

Конечно, чтобы лучше понимать русскую орфоэпию, нужно освоить хотя бы азы фонетики. Можете прочитать соответствующие разделы из учебника Князева – Пожарицкой. Читать Розенталя для этого довольно странно, ведь его справочник посвящен прежде всего письменной разновидности языка.

«Ослабленный [а]», о котором вы упомянули, вероятно, тот, который встречается в первом слоге слова *корова*. Если вы не окаете, то есть не произносите два звука [о] в слове *корова*, то, скорее всего, «ослабленный [а]» воспроизводить умеете без всяких описаний в книжках.

Answer (score 1):

Изучение русского произношения связано **с двумя темами**: (1) Фонетическое чередование звуков; (2) Правила орфоэпии.

**В первой теме** даются основные правила изменения звуков в слабых позициях (безударная позиция для гласных и позиции для согласных, в которых они оглушаются, озвончаются, смягчаются, не произносятся и т.д.).

**Во второй теме** изучается материал более частного характера, то есть отнесенный к отдельным группам слов, сочетаний звуков и т.д.  Этот же материал дается в орфоэпических словарях, при этом желательно пользоваться современными изданиями, так как возможны изменения.

Отдельно рассматривается **тема правильного ударения**, в основном на практическом уровне. Можно ознакомиться и с теорией, но она довольно сложная для практического применения (это, например, акцентные группы слов, которые есть в Грамматике-80). В словаре И. Резниченко (Словарь ударений русского языка, 2004) есть немного теоретического материала по этой теме, это вообще интересный словарь с примерами и историей ударения для некоторых слов.

С другой стороны, **нормированное ударение** (в последней версии) всегда можно найти на Грамоте.ру, так что орфоэпические словари здесь как бы необязательны. (Такие словари полезны при поиске  дополнительной информации, если слово имеет варианты.)

Я думаю, что прежде всего вам надо ознакомиться **с материалами на Грамоте.ру** http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/textbooks/author/litnevskaya/part1
Возможно, это как раз **то, что вам требуется на начальном этапе.**

Comment: Спасибо большое. Извините, пожалуйста, если так делать тут не принято, но вот этот вопрос мне никак не дает покоя, а ответов нет. Мне бы было достаточно малюсенького пояснения, лишь бы разобраться:https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461594/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%8a%d1%8f%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be

Comment: К сожалению, на форуме нет личной почты, а она не помешала бы, поэтому иногда приходится обращаться таким образом. Я отвечу чуть позже, всё-таки любой вопрос требует внимания, не на каждый можно ответить сразу. К тому же мне тоже хотелось бы услышать чье-либо мнение, ведь несколько ответов на один вопрос всегда полнее и интереснее раскрывают тему. Именно по этой причине я не всегда спешу отвечать первой.