# Объясните, пожалуйста, данное правило

Tags: орфография, морфология, частица-не, прилагательные

Правило у Розенталя:
https://old-rozental.online/orfograf_uk.php?oid=2318

> 11. Пишутся раздельно с частицей не краткие формы прилагательных, которые не употребляются в полной форме или имеют в полной форме иное значение: не готов к отъезду; не должен так поступать; не намерен молчать; не обязан помогать; не рад встрече; не склонен верить; не расположен к беседе и др.

Объясните, пожалуйста, про какое другое значение говорит Розенталь? Например, «Не готовый к выходу актёр» и «Не готов к отъезду». Разве здесь есть другое значение? Заранее огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ исправлен (вторая редакция)

Данная тема регулируется двумя правилами Розенталя.

**ЧИТАЕМ РОЗЕНТАЛЯ:** http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77

**Правило 8.** Раздельное написание частицы НЕ с прилагательным, имеющим при себе пояснительные слова, встречается:  при прилагательных, которые в полной и краткой формах имеют разное значение: не готовый к выходу актёр;

**Правило 11.** Пишутся раздельно с частицей НЕ   краткие формы прилагательных, которые не употребляются в полной форме или имеют в полной форме иное значение: не готов к отъезду;

**О ЧЕМ ЗДЕСЬ ГОВОРИТСЯ?**

В толковом словаре для прилагательного ***готовый*** обозначены несколько значений, из которых нам будут интересны значения (1) и (4) с предлогом К.

**В значении (1)** прилагательное может иметь обе формы (полную и краткую), но при этом требуется наличие **обязательных зависимых слов** (есть указание на падежный вопрос: готовый к чему). **В значении (4)** прилагательное употребляется только **в краткой форме**.

**Эти ограничения разные**, но они приводят к одному и тому же следствию, а именно:  возможно т**олько раздельное написание НЕ**. Это следует из схемы образования полной и краткой формы.

**При наличии обязательных зависимых слов** частица НЕ относится к словосочетанию, а не к одному слову, поэтому нет формы ***неготовый*** (с приставкой НЕ). Но тогда нет и краткой формы ***неготов***, которая может образоваться только от полной формы.

Схема образования: ***готовый к чему-либо – не готовый к  чему-либо – не готов к чему-либо.***

При наличии только краткой формы схема образования такова: ***готов – не готов,*** то есть формы ***неготов*** также нет.

**ПРОВЕРИМ ФОРМУЛИРОВКУ ПРАВИЛА У РОЗЕНТАЛЯ**

**Правило 11** вполне корректно.  В нашем случае оно относится к значению (4), когда используется только  краткая форма готов.  Полная форма готовый хотя и существует, но она имеет другое значение (1). Соответственно, НЕ пишется раздельно: ***обед не готов***.

**Правило (8)** мне корректным не кажется. В нашем случае оно относится к значению (1), а **само правило я  бы  записала так**:  При наличии обязательных пояснительных слов НЕ пишется только раздельно в обеих формах: ***не готовый к выходу актер – актер не готов к выходу.***

**ПРАКТИЧЕСКОЕ ПИСЬМО**

На практике мы видим следующее. В  Нацкорпусе  формы с приставкой НЕ встречаются очень редко: ***неготовый*** – 6 примеров, ***неготов*** – 1 пример. Такие написания можно считать частными случаями, поэтому делаем вывод:  НЕ пишется только раздельно в обеих формах: ***не готовый и не готов***.

Исключения возможны, но они частного характера и, вероятно, связаны с переносным значением слова «неготовый». Кстати, в словаре такое написание отмечено как существующее.

**ОТВЕТ НА ВОПРОС**

Объясните, пожалуйста, про какое другое значение говорит Розенталь? Например, «Не готовый к выходу актёр» и «Не готов к отъезду».

Вопрос задан по правилу 11, но примеры приведены из разных правил.
Смешение двух правил (8 и 11), а также не вполне корректная формулировка правила (8) у Розенталя привели к непониманию смысла.

Здесь речь идет о значении (1) для прилагательного ***готовый***, а в этом случае раздельное написание НЕ связано с наличие обязательных зависимых слов из правила 8, а не с разными значениями полной и краткой формы из правила 11 (значение у этих форм в данном случае одинаковое).

**УВАЖАЕМЫЙ АВТОР ВОПРОСА!**

1. Как вы видите, объяснение не получается коротким. Правила Розенталя рассчитаны **на заучивание, а не на понимание**. К тому же я допускаю, что некорректность формулировки допустил не сам Розенталь, а его многочисленные редакторы. У людей не всегда хватает внимания и терпения, чтобы разобраться в смысле чего-либо, и тогда они относятся к  предмету формально и небрежно.
2. **Я написала ответ по вашей просьбе.** Я не уверена, что этот материал будет понятен вам или интересен кому-либо еще. Если на нем не окажется никаких пометок с вашей стороны или со стороны участников форума, то я удалю ответ.

Comment: Вы бы знали, как я вам благодарен! Но эта тема действительна сложна. Буду пока разбираться!

Comment: Я, безусловно, ставлю плюс за такой обстоятельный ответ, галочку поставлю попозже, когда окончательно пойму ваше объяснение! Ещё раз спасибо за то, что откликаетесь на мои вопросы!

Comment: Игорь, меня не галочки интересуют,  мне просто хотелось знать, что ответ читает хотя бы кто-то, меня бы устроил любой комментарий. Тема сложная, что и говорить. Мне орфографические темы  напоминают заброшенное жильё, которым давно и никто не интересуется. Орфография за 11 лет обучения худо-бедно усваивается, у пользователей  больше проблем с пунктуацией.  А здесь время будто остановилось: всё-надо переписывать с учетом новых информационных возможностей, но никому до этого дела нет. Если вам что-то будет непонятно, то спрашивайте. И если уж начали изучать тему, то лучше довести дело до конца.

Comment: Только до конца разобравшись, я понял, насколько ваш ответ точен, лаконичен и полностью корректен. Этот материал оказался мне полностью понятен благодаря вам. Спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо, Игорь!

Comment: Уже не поправить комментарий, к сожалению ( По сути, написал «насколько полностью корректен». Извиняюсь за тавтологию.